# Download Image In Current Browser Window Like Google Chrome

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

With the help of **Alvaro Montoro:**
Here is my **Javascript function:**

```
 function imageloadingdown() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        var hiddenIFrameId = 'hiddenDownloader';
        var iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameId);
        if (iframe === null) {
            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.id = hiddenIFrameId;
            iframe.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }
        iframe.src = url;
    }
```

Here is my **Html code:**

```
 <table>
   <tr data-report_id="5">
    <td>

        <iframe id="hiddenDownloader"/>
    <td>
</tr>
        </table>
```

Now i have no **server side code:**
Here is the **Output:**
[image]

It appends the output in the current page,but i want to download it like **google chrome** does,as shown in figure below.Kindly help me out.

[image]

Comment: Some one please help me...

Comment: You could try something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55488/File-Download-Using-JavaScript. And have you checked the suggested solutions for similar problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668776/download-file-through-an-ajax-call-php or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092984/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-wcf-service-stream

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro...Thanks,but it is not downloading the image like the image attached,kindly help me, how to do that.

Comment: If you don't know the answer,then atleast don't vote down my question

Comment: 1) I didn't vote down your question. 2) I do have work to do. 3) I gave you 3 links with questions similar to yours (solved!). 4) I don't know the answer directly; but if I work on it I'd probably find it, and it would definitely be a mix of the links I posted previously. 5) What have you tried? So far it looks like you did nothing but ask on StackOverflow and wait for someone to work for free for you.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro...i did not mention you,that you have down vote me.....i think it little bit misunderstanding

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro...help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.aspx` your code should be as follows:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Submit"  Style="display: none"  OnClick="btnDownload_Click"/>
```

In `.cs`,your code is as follows:

```
protected void DownloadFile(string fileName)        {

                fileName = hdnFileNameDms.Value;
                string practiceCode = Profile.PracticeCode;
                // string filepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/WEBEHR/DMS/Documents/" + practiceCode + "/" + fileName);
                string filepath = hdnFilePath.Value;
                FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(filepath);

                string webfile = String.Empty;
                string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "WEBEHR", "webehr" };
                string[] fileurl = filepath.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
                string[] weburls = url.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (fileurl.Length > 1 && weburls.Length > 1)
                {
                    webfile = weburls[0] + "webehr" + fileurl[1];
                }


                if (Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("iphone") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("ipad") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("mobile"))
                {
                    IpadResponseHelperDMS.Redirect(webfile, "_blank", "menubar=0,width=100,height=100");
                    return;
                }
                Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(fileinfo.Extension.ToLower());
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName.Replace(",", ""));
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileinfo.Length.ToString());
                Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath));
                Response.End();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is **not** for downloading files. There are multiple options for achieving what you want to do:

1. Pop up a window with the link to the file in the address (or use window.location. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6668806/3695983).
2. Have a hidden iframe and change the source to the link of the file you want to download (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22455488/3695983).
3. Create a form and send the information to get the file (instead of using AJAX. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13322848/3695983).

Consider adding these headers to the page that returns the file (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9858790/3695983):

```
Content-Type:'application/force-download'
Content-Disposition:'attachment; filename=the_filename'
```

That in your case would probably be something like this (I have not tested it, you'll have to do it):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/force-download;";
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileInfo.Name);
```

---

You can read more about these solutions on the links:

- [Download file through an ajax call php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668776/download-file-through-an-ajax-call-php) (I know it's PHP, but the solution applies to any language)
- [how to force download dialog for a text file on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896211/how-to-force-download-dialog-for-a-text-file-on-the-server)
- [starting file download with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365777/starting-file-download-with-javascript)

With all the information above you should be more than able to fix the problem. Good luck with the development!